# Singularity Of $f(z)=\frac{z}{z-2i}\cos (\frac{z}{3})$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)=\frac{z}{z-2i}\cos (\frac{z}{3})$

It seems that to find the limit will be hard so

$f(z)=\frac{z}{z-2i}\cos (\frac{z}{3})=\frac{z}{z-2i}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{3^2n\cdot2n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{3^2n\cdot2n!(z-2i)}$

What to do next?

Comment: What limit you want to find ? $f$ has a simple pole at $2 i$ and no other singularities.

Comment: @Fred Why can we conclude right away that there is a simple pole at $2i$?

Comment: What is your definition of "simple pole" ?

Comment: @Fred I look at the order of zero of $f(z)$

Comment: $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z-2i}$ where $g(z) = z\cos(z/3)$ is an analytic function in $\Bbb C$